# Два параметра в ссылке

Tags: php, get, pagination

У меня есть сайт со статьями. За их вывод отвечает файл `list.php`. В шапке сайта находиться список категорий к которым относятся посты сайта. Я сделал пагинатор для сайта и со всеми статьями он работает хорошо, но как сделать так что бы при клике на какую-то категорию выводились статьи именно с этой категории(ну и что бы пагинатор работал)?

`id` категорий у меня находятся в `$_GET['id']`. Я пытаюсь сделать это так: если в `$_GET['id']` что то есть то делать запрос в базу данных с фильтром по категориям, если же там ничего нет то запрос будет брать все статьи без фильтра. Все приходит нормально и по категориям переходит тоже но когда я нажимаю перейти на следующую страницу, там, вне зависимости от категории в которой я был, те посты, которые просто подходят под пагинацию, т.е. отсортированы вне зависимости от категории.

Вот запросы:

```
$per_page = 5;
$page = 1;
$offest = ($per_page * $page) - $per_page;
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $articles = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `categorie_id` = ".$_GET['id'].
    " ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $offest,$per_page");
} else {
  $articles = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $offest,$per_page");
}
```

Я знаю что в ссылке(см.скрин) должно быть два параметра: `id` и `page` но я не могу понять как это реализовать, буду очень признателен за помощь.

[image: Id and Page]

Comment: `categories.php?id=5&page=1` и `$_GET['page']`

Comment: Используете построитель запросов , например https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/ru/zend.db.select.html . На прямом SQL в виде текста очень проблематично вообще строить фильтры и отсеивания, потом кто-то очень сильно будет ругаться матом на такой код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то вам при отрисовке пагинатора на странице категории необходимо в параметрах передавать помимо номера страницы также идентификатор категории.

Соответственно, ссылки перехода должны выглядеть как то так:

```
echo '<a href="categories.php?page='.$page_index.'&id='.$category_id.'">'.$page_index.'/a>';
```

Соответственно в вашем коде

```
$page = 1;
```

заменить на

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
```